# Why FormGroup.Get() returns null if FormControl have '.' in the name?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

**Problem:**
I have created a `formGroup` using `formbuilder`. FormGroup have a control which have `.` in the name. Now when I try to get `formControl` using `formGroup.get` method it's returning **null**.

**Code**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  obj = {};
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obj["parent.child"] = new FormControl();
    this.obj["parent"] = new FormControl();

    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(this.obj);

    // All controls
    console.log(this.formGroup.controls);

    // This is the problem its not geting the form control if I have '.' in the name of form control.
    console.log(this.formGroup.get("parent.child"));

    // If I am getting formControl without '.' then it is returning correctly.
    console.log(this.formGroup.get("parent"));
  }
}
```

Here I have a stackbiltz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grjh7e?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within your question. By including it within your question, we can ensure the question is still helpful when the external link is no longer available.

Comment: @DavidWalschots Okay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `FormGroup.get()` it will search using "." as a key separator so it will start by trying to find the control "cz" and fail because it does not exist (returning `null`).

What this function is expecting when you provide a dot-separated string is this:

```
{
    "cz": {
        "datalite": {
            "makro": { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
this.formGroup.get(["parent.child"]);
```

Working Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grjh7e?file=src/app/app.component.ts